# Nested Question Toggle using Radio Buttons

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms, radio-button

I have a relatively straightforward nested question setup using radio buttons and JavaScript/jQuery which shows/hides extra information based on the button that you click (Yes to show, No to hide):

Here is the HTML:

```
          <div class="form-nest panel-question d-flex justify-content-start">
              <span class="icon icon-primary icon-medium icon-roundel icon-vehicle align-self-start mr-2 mr-md-4"></span>
                            <div class="question-wrapper">
            <h2 class="heading-epsilon">Are you interested in RAC Breakdown Cover for complete peace of mind?</h2>
           <!-- Yes/no Open-->
          <div class="form-row form-inline">
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline"><input class="form-check-input form-check-input-button" type="radio" name="buttonRadio3" id="buttonRadio5"><label for="buttonRadio5">Yes</label></div>
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline"><input class="form-check-input form-check-input-button" type="radio" name="buttonRadio3" id="buttonRadio6"><label for="buttonRadio6">No</label></div>
          </div>
           <!-- Yes/no closed -->

            </div><!--question-wrapper-->
        </div><!-- Form Nest Close-->
        <!--Nested container open -->
          <div class="nested-container">
            <div id="buttonRadio5-nest" class="nested-content">
              <ul class="list list-icons">
              <li class="list-item list-icon list-icon-tick">Pays out regardless of whether the accident was fault or non-fault</li>
              <li class="list-item list-icon list-icon-tick">Covers named drivers and passengers</li>
              <li class="list-item list-icon list-icon-tick">Covers the policy holder when driving other vehicles if they don't own the vehicle</li>
              </ul>
            <a href="#">View more product information</a>
            <p><strong>+ £40.00</strong> per year</p>
            <div class="form-row form-inline">
              <div class="form-check form-check-inline"><input class="form-check-input form-check-input-button" type="checkbox" name="buttonCheckbox1" id="buttonCheckbox1"><label for="buttonCheckbox1">Add</label></div>
            </div>
            </div>
          </div><!-- Nested container closed -->
```

And the JS/jQuery:

```
function nestedPanelHide(ele) {
  var eleId = "#" + ele,
      nestWrap = $(eleId).closest(".form-nest"),
      nestCont = nestWrap.next(".nested-container");

  nestCont.children().hide();
}

function nestedPanelShow(ele) {  
  var eleId = "#" + ele,
      nestWrap = $(eleId).closest(".form-nest"),
      nestCont = nestWrap.next(".nested-container"),
      eleNestId = eleId + "-nest",
      nestFields = nestCont.children(eleNestId);

  nestedPanelHide(ele);
  nestFields.show();
}

$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".nested-content").hide();

  // Find each form with nest class
  $(".form-nest").each(function( index ) {

    // Find nest conts
    var nest = $(this),
        nestCont = nest.next(".nested-container");

    // For each nest cont
    for (var i = 0; i < nestCont.length; i++) {

      // Find nest opts in cont
      var nestOpt = nestCont[i].children;

      // For each nest opt add click event
      for (var j = 0; j < nestOpt.length; j++) {

        // Get cont id, trim to form ele id
        var id = nestOpt[j].id,
            str = id.substr(0, id.lastIndexOf("-")),
            eleId = "#" + str;

        // Add class to ele to remove from later look up
        $(eleId).parent().addClass("nest-btn");

        // Add show event listener to ele
        $(eleId).on("click", function() {          
          var id = $(this).attr("id");
          nestedPanelShow(id);
        });
      }
    }

    // Find nest opts
    var nestOpts = nest.children();

    // For each nest opt
    for (var k = 0; k < nestOpts.length; k++) {

      // Get this opt
      var opt = $(nestOpts[k]);

      // If opt does not have class nest-btn
      if (!opt.hasClass("nest-btn")) {

        // Add hide event listener to opt
        $(opt.children()).on("click", function() {          
          var id = $(this).attr("id");
          nestedPanelHide(id);
        });
      }
    }
  });
});

function nestedPanelHide(ele) {
  var eleId = "#" + ele,
      nestWrap = $(eleId).closest(".form-nest"),
      nestCont = nestWrap.next(".nested-container");

  nestCont.children().hide();
}

function nestedPanelShow(ele) {  
  var eleId = "#" + ele,
      nestWrap = $(eleId).closest(".form-nest"),
      nestCont = nestWrap.next(".nested-container"),
      eleNestId = eleId + "-nest",
      nestFields = nestCont.children(eleNestId);

  nestedPanelHide(ele);
  nestFields.show();
}

$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".nested-content").hide();

  // Find each form with nest class
  $(".form-nest").each(function( index ) {

    // Find nest conts
    var nest = $(this),
        nestCont = nest.next(".nested-container");

    // For each nest cont
    for (var i = 0; i < nestCont.length; i++) {

      // Find nest opts in cont
      var nestOpt = nestCont[i].children;

      // For each nest opt add click event
      for (var j = 0; j < nestOpt.length; j++) {

        // Get cont id, trim to form ele id
        var id = nestOpt[j].id,
            str = id.substr(0, id.lastIndexOf("-")),
            eleId = "#" + str;

        // Add class to ele to remove from later look up
        $(eleId).parent().addClass("nest-btn");

        // Add show event listener to ele
        $(eleId).on("click", function() {          
          var id = $(this).attr("id");
          nestedPanelShow(id);
        });
      }
    }

    // Find nest opts
    var nestOpts = nest.children();

    // For each nest opt
    for (var k = 0; k < nestOpts.length; k++) {

      // Get this opt
      var opt = $(nestOpts[k]);

      // If opt does not have class nest-btn
      if (!opt.hasClass("nest-btn")) {

        // Add hide event listener to opt
        $(opt.children()).on("click", function() {          
          var id = $(this).attr("id");
          nestedPanelHide(id);
        });
      }
    }
  });
});


(function($) {

$('.label-yes').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.nested-content').addClass('open');
});

$('.label-no').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.nested-content').removeClass('open');
});

})(jQuery);
```

I can get the extra information to display when you click on "yes" but I can't get it to hide again when you click "no". I've tried going over line-by-line to see if I can identify where my error might be. I feel like it's something simple, but I fear I may have gone a little code blind from staring at it too much.

I have a JSfiddle here which shows you the basis of what I'm trying to achieve - I've stripped out the styling as it might give away who this is for (it's client work), but the basic functionality is there:

https://jsfiddle.net/3y4b25uk/

Any help or guidance that can be given would be greatly appreciated as I'm at the end of my tether trying to get it working and it's so nearly there.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a few issues - there are no elements with the classes `label-yes` and `label-no`, there is no class `open`, the selectors in the `click()` events for `label-yes` and `label-no` do not select the div with the class `nested-content` as this is not selectable with `closest`. The div with the class nested-conent is displayed upon click of "yes" not because of the `click()` event that is attached to `label-yes`, but because of a click() event you have earlier in your code in the `$(".form-nest").each()` function:

```
$(eleId).on("click", function() {
   var id = $(this).attr("id");
   nestedPanelShow(id);
});
```

To get the click() functions for label-yes and label-no working, I've added these classes to the input elements, added the class `open`, set the `nested-content` element to `display:none` via CSS and adjusted the selector in the `click()` events from

```
 $(this).closest('.nested-content')
```

to

```
 $(this).closest(".form-nest").next(".nested-container").find(".nested-content")
```

Working example:

```js
function nestedPanelHide(ele) {
  var eleId = "#" + ele,
    nestWrap = $(eleId).closest(".form-nest"),
    nestCont = nestWrap.next(".nested-container");

  nestCont.children().hide();
}

function nestedPanelShow(ele) {
  var eleId = "#" + ele,
    nestWrap = $(eleId).closest(".form-nest"),
    nestCont = nestWrap.next(".nested-container"),
    eleNestId = eleId + "-nest",
    nestFields = nestCont.children(eleNestId);

  nestedPanelHide(ele);
  nestFields.show();
}

$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".nested-content").hide();

  // Find each form with nest class
  $(".form-nest").each(function(index) {

    // Find nest conts
    var nest = $(this),
      nestCont = nest.next(".nested-container");

    // For each nest cont
    for (var i = 0; i < nestCont.length; i++) {

      // Find nest opts in cont
      var nestOpt = nestCont[i].children;

      // For each nest opt add click event
      for (var j = 0; j < nestOpt.length; j++) {

        // Get cont id, trim to form ele id
        var id = nestOpt[j].id,
          str = id.substr(0, id.lastIndexOf("-")),
          eleId = "#" + str;

        // Add class to ele to remove from later look up
        $(eleId).parent().addClass("nest-btn");

        // Add show event listener to ele
        $(eleId).on("click", function() {
          var id = $(this).attr("id");
          nestedPanelShow(id);
        });
      }
    }

    // Find nest opts
    var nestOpts = nest.children();

    // For each nest opt
    for (var k = 0; k < nestOpts.length; k++) {

      // Get this opt
      var opt = $(nestOpts[k]);

      // If opt does not have class nest-btn
      if (!opt.hasClass("nest-btn")) {

        // Add hide event listener to opt
        $(opt.children()).on("click", function() {
          var id = $(this).attr("id");
          nestedPanelHide(id);
        });
      }
    }
  });
});

function nestedPanelHide(ele) {
  var eleId = "#" + ele,
    nestWrap = $(eleId).closest(".form-nest"),
    nestCont = nestWrap.next(".nested-container");

  nestCont.children().hide();
}

function nestedPanelShow(ele) {
  var eleId = "#" + ele,
    nestWrap = $(eleId).closest(".form-nest"),
    nestCont = nestWrap.next(".nested-container"),
    eleNestId = eleId + "-nest",
    nestFields = nestCont.children(eleNestId);

  nestedPanelHide(ele);
  nestFields.show();
}

$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".nested-content").hide();

  // Find each form with nest class
  $(".form-nest").each(function(index) {

    // Find nest conts
    var nest = $(this),
      nestCont = nest.next(".nested-container");

    // For each nest cont
    for (var i = 0; i < nestCont.length; i++) {

      // Find nest opts in cont
      var nestOpt = nestCont[i].children;

      // For each nest opt add click event
      for (var j = 0; j < nestOpt.length; j++) {

        // Get cont id, trim to form ele id
        var id = nestOpt[j].id,
          str = id.substr(0, id.lastIndexOf("-")),
          eleId = "#" + str;

        // Add class to ele to remove from later look up
        $(eleId).parent().addClass("nest-btn");

        // Add show event listener to ele
        $(eleId).on("click", function() {
          var id = $(this).attr("id");
          nestedPanelShow(id);
        });
      }
    }

    // Find nest opts
    var nestOpts = nest.children();

    // For each nest opt
    for (var k = 0; k < nestOpts.length; k++) {

      // Get this opt
      var opt = $(nestOpts[k]);

      // If opt does not have class nest-btn
      if (!opt.hasClass("nest-btn")) {

        // Add hide event listener to opt
        $(opt.children()).on("click", function() {
          var id = $(this).attr("id");
          nestedPanelHide(id);
        });
      }
    }
  });
});


(function($) {

  $('.label-yes').click(function() {
  $(this).closest(".form-nest").next(".nested-container").find(".nested-content").addClass("open");
  });

  $('.label-no').click(function() {
  $(this).closest(".form-nest").next(".nested-container").find(".nested-content").removeClass("open");
  });

})(jQuery);
```

```css
.sandbox{
     .panel-question{
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
    }
    .form-row.form-inline {
    width: 100%;
    }
}
.nested-content {
  display:none;
}
.open {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="sandbox">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="panel">
          <div class="panel-content">
            <div class="form-nest panel-question d-flex justify-content-start">
              <span class="icon icon-primary icon-medium icon-roundel icon-vehicle align-self-start mr-2 mr-md-4"></span>
              <div class="question-wrapper">
                <h2 class="heading-epsilon">Are you interested in RAC Breakdown Cover for complete peace of mind?</h2>
                <!-- Yes/no Open-->
                <div class="form-row form-inline">
                  <div class="form-check form-check-inline"><input class="form-check-input form-check-input-button label-yes" type="radio" name="buttonRadio3" id="buttonRadio5"><label for="buttonRadio5">Yes</label></div>
                  <div class="form-check form-check-inline"><input class="form-check-input form-check-input-button label-no" type="radio" name="buttonRadio3" id="buttonRadio6"><label for="buttonRadio6">No</label></div>
                </div>
                <!-- Yes/no closed -->

              </div>
              <!--question-wrapper-->
            </div><!-- Form Nest Close-->
            <!--Nested container open -->
            <div class="nested-container">
              <div id="buttonRadio5-nest" class="nested-content">
                <ul class="list list-icons">
                  <li class="list-item list-icon list-icon-tick">Pays out regardless of whether the accident was fault or non-fault</li>
                  <li class="list-item list-icon list-icon-tick">Covers named drivers and passengers</li>
                  <li class="list-item list-icon list-icon-tick">Covers the policy holder when driving other vehicles if they don't own the vehicle</li>
                </ul>
                <a href="#">View more product information</a>
                <p><strong>+ £40.00</strong> per year</p>
                <div class="form-row form-inline">
                  <div class="form-check form-check-inline"><input class="form-check-input form-check-input-button" type="checkbox" name="buttonCheckbox1" id="buttonCheckbox1"><label for="buttonCheckbox1">Add</label></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div><!-- Nested container closed -->

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Note that the `<div>` with the class `nested-content` now gets displayed because of 2 reasons: once because of the working `click()` event handler on `label-yes`, and in addition because of the previous `click()` event that calls the function `nestedPanelShow()`. I'm not sure if you want to remove this `click()` event or rework your code so you're also attaching a `click()` event to the input for "No" and can omit the additional `click()` events you attach to `label-yes` and `label-no`. I've added a console message to this event handler in this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ke3n1spz/).